# Craft 2.6 CMS Posts Overloading Servers

Tags: performance, hosting

We've had a half a dozen cases now of people editing content in different Craft 2.6 sites taking down our webservers.

- One staff member here editing a basic entry in the CMS has taken down a large cloud server multiple times over the past couple of months.
- A group of 20~ students uploading some basic projects in the CMS took down a different quad core webserver with 12GB of RAM and spiked the load to 250 - again multiple times.

I have little info to go off at this stage but I do know the load was caused by post requests made by php from the CMS. Front end traffic isn't the issue.

I'm nervous enough about this at the moment that the latest craft site I launched is on its own VPS to keep it away from other sites.

--

Happy to provide login/server deets to any of the Craft guys if they're curious, or if there's any more info people want, please let me know.

Comment: Going to be difficult to debug this remotely, I'd guess. You have any sort of server/processing monitoring software in place to at least see what's running amok while it's happening?  Might also be worth looking at https://newrelic.com/.

Comment: Server specs? How are you running your instances?   FPM? fastcgi? mod_php on apache?  When you mention "took down a server", did you lock up with an OOM (out of memory) or what exactly happened?  If you run Apache using mod_php, for example, every request—even static requests—are going to fire up PHP and consume whatever memory that is set to.  If 20 students are uploading at the same time and Apache has 256 MB allowed to it, you're about halfway through ram. Combine that with serving some static assets and I can see how you might blow through an instance. Just tuning can go a long way here...

Comment: If you have a lot of content and are using the built-in {% cache %} tag, it could be the "Delete stale template cache" task that kicks in when users save content. See my answers on these two questions, maybe that'll help explain what's happening: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/15925/141 and http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/17149/141