# compiled_templates folder using up inodes on Ubuntu 14.04 Server

Tags: database, config, php, server

My server has gone down twice in the last 3 weeks because of an excessive number of files being created in the compiled_templates folder. This causes all of the inodes on our server to be used up causing the site to crash.

We previously thought this may have been because of a security test that hit multiple URLs on the site and generated too many templates. The original question can be seen here [Security test generated large compiled_templates directory, site outage](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20985/security-test-generated-large-compiled-templates-directory-site-outage)

This time there was no unusual traffic spike, so I can't assume it was because of the security testing. The only common thread seems to be that garbage collection is either not deleting the old compiled templates or craft is mis-configured. Any insights into this issue would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Looking in the `compiled_templates` folder it seems there are a few hundred different folders with names like 00 a9 b3 ... and inside those folders are sometimes hundreds of PHP files. I can't track down what templates some of them go to. For example one of the comments up to reads: `/* __string_template__cc8a06d92434271d04fe341ad237b568da4c65f004cfec4d1fc576ee4e9b6c4a */`

They have functions that echo out single lines of text, these functions are called doDisplay. I am not the original author of this site and am not an expert at Craft. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yeah, I've just discovered a Craft site that has a `/craft/runtime/compiled_templates` folder that is 1.3GB! Still investigating.

Answer (score 1):

How many files are in the `compiled_templates` directory? There should be a 1:1 correlation between the number of actual templates you have, and the number of cached `.php` compiled templates in the `compiled_templates`folder.

It shouldn't have anything to do with 404 errors, etc.

I've never seen nor heard of the situation that you've described.

Comment: Additionally at the top of every compiled template is a comment with the source template that it was compiled from.  Might help in tracking down where they are coming from.

Comment: There are probably over a hundred folders with various names like '00' 'a9' 'a8' and inside those folders there are a hundred other php files with names like 00f1fbe8f11466faed7ba834b345155794841b35579c9839f1a01a1d5242d164.php

Comment: Can you peek at the files as per Brad's suggestion, to see where they are all coming from? Something definitely doesn't sound right here.

Comment: @khalwat I updated the main question above but they are all coming from string templates of some sort. The comments at the top of the files read like this: "/* __string_template__cc8a06d92434271d04fe341ad237b568da4c65f004cfec4d1fc576ee4e9b6c4a */"

Comment: Brad, khalwat, thank you for the context so far. I wanted to give some additional background on what we're seeing when these string templates generate: we recently upgraded from Craft 2.3 to 2.6, and had a few macro templates with template_from_string invocations that looked like: `include(template_from_string(page.name)|raw|e)` -- these would throw an error after the upgrade, and we had to remove the |raw|e filters to avoid "Unable to find the template __string_template__8c58...." errors.

Comment: After that change, we are seeing unique templates generated for each page refresh - for example, where we would expect one file containing "A very special string" template after 6 page refreshes, instead we see 6: https://pastebin.com/Ecq36Myv

Comment: Something that led us to believe that these Twig templates were being treated differently in this version was this answer: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/16268/6917 - not sure if this is applicable. FWIW, also not the author or a Craft expert.

Answer (score 1):

If the compiled template class names start with `__string_template`, then that means the source template doesn't live in the `craft/templates` folder, but it was rendered at runtime by calling Twig's `Environment->createTemplate()`.

Craft does this for rendering Twig strings to a template for things like a Section's Entry URL Format settings, which can be any valid Twig code.

Plugins can also do this as well.  Do you happen to have the [Preparse](https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft) plugin installed?  Seems like a potential candidate if so.

A bit of a hacky workaround, but you could always setup a cron-job to delete the contents of that folder either full-on or based on some other logic (how old they are, number of files, etc.).  They'll get re-generated as needed.